# Extending LdapLoginModule is not authorizing user

Tags: java, jboss, ldap, jaas, j-security-check

I was trying to install my custom authentication(required in the application) using JAAS.
My standalone.xml looks like

```
<security-domain name="other" cache-type="default">
                <authentication>
                    <login-module code="com.app.user.extendedSec.ExtendedLdapExtLoginModule" flag="optional">
                        <module-option name="java.naming.factory.initial" value="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"/>
                        <module-option name="java.naming.provider.url" value="ldap://app.user.in:389"/>
                        <module-option name="java.naming.security.authentication" value="simple"/>
                        <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                        <module-option name="principalDNPrefix" value="cn="/>
                        <module-option name="principalDNSuffix" value=",OU=Test,DC=ads,DC=exilant,DC=in"/>
                        <module-option name="rolesCtxDN" value="OU=Test,DC=ads,DC=exilant,DC=in"/>
                        <module-option name="uidAttributeID" value="member"/>
                        <module-option name="matchOnUserDN" value="false"/>
                        <module-option name="roleAttributeID" value="sAMAccountName"/>
                        <module-option name="roleAttributeIsDN" value="true"/>
                    </login-module>
                    <login-module code="com.app.user.extendedSec.ExtendedUsernamePasswordLoginModule" flag="required">
                        <module-option name="unauthenticatedIdentity" value="guest"/>
                        <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                        <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:/session-tracking-dataSource-orcl"/>
                        <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="SELECT PASSWORD FROM FUSION_USERS WHERE USERID=? AND LOCKFLAG='false' and (upper(active_ind) != 'N' or active_ind is null)"/>
                        <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="SELECT USERTYPE, 'Roles' FROM FUSION_USER_GROUPS WHERE USERID=?"/>
                    </login-module>
```

When it is authenticating and authorizing using DB it is working fine. But is not able to authenticate/authorize using ldap server

```
public class ExtendedLdapExtLoginModule extends LdapLoginModule {

private static Logger _logger=Logger.getLogger(ExtendedLdapExtLoginModule.class.getClass());



/**
 * @param inputPassword: encrypted password from request; expectedPassword: password from active directive
 * @return passed to the super class. True for success, false for failure.
 */
@Override
protected boolean validatePassword(String inputPassword, String expectedPassword) {
    _logger.debug("ExtendedLdapExtLoginModule: Input encrypted: " + inputPassword);
    _logger.debug("ExtendedLdapExtLoginModule: Input decrypted: " + PasswordCodec.getDecryptedPassword(inputPassword));
    _logger.debug("ExtendedLdapExtLoginModule: Expected: " +expectedPassword);

    //  Decrypt the password before pass it for comparison
    return super.validatePassword(PasswordCodec.getDecryptedPassword(inputPassword), expectedPassword);
}
```

}

The password is getting decrypted at server side correctly.

Am i missing something here?

Thanks

Comment: The way you are trying to compare two plaintexts won't work. LDAP servers usually do not allow password retrieval. You will have to perform a login to the LDAP server, called a `bind`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are extending `org.jboss.security.auth.spi.LdapLoginModule`, you should not override `validatePassword()` as it already tries to do a *bind* operation to the LDAP server.

Judging from the source code and comments at the [JBoss docs](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/javadoc/4.0.2/org/jboss/security/auth/spi/LdapLoginModule.java.html) you can just use the vanilla `LdapLoginModule#validatePassword()` and it will try a login instead of password retrieval.

Specifically, these comments from the JBoss source code clarify this:

```
/** Overriden to return an empty password string as typically one cannot
obtain a user's password. We also override the validatePassword so
this is ok.
@return and empty password String
*/
protected String getUsersPassword() throws LoginException
{
  return "";
}

/** Validate the inputPassword by creating a ldap InitialContext with the
SECURITY_CREDENTIALS set to the password.

@param inputPassword the password to validate.
@param expectedPassword ignored
*/
protected boolean validatePassword(String inputPassword, String expectedPassword)
```